# How to check which axioms hold for models in set theory?

Tags: set-theory

I started a class in set theory. The professor drew a few diagrams, all of them having big circles on the outside. Inside there are two small circles marked $a$ and $b$. And they have arrows between them. For one example, one diagram simply has $a$ and $b$ without any arrows. Another one has an arrow from $a$ to $b$ and another arrow from $b$ to $a$. The question is which of these models satisfy the Axiom of Extensionality. I am very confused because the first one seems not to satisfy and the second one does. Can anyone tell me what these diagrams mean and why the axiom holds or does not?

Comment: What are the arrows intended to signify?  It's hard to tell from your description what the diagrams have to do with satisfying or not satisfying the Axiom of Extensionality, which says two sets are distinct if and only if they have differences among their members.

Comment: I believe the arrows are intended to signify the $\in$ relation, the only relation defined in the basic language of set theory.

Comment: You are right, Dustan.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that the arrows are the graph for $\in$ of that model. Namely there is an arrow from $x$ to $y$ if $x\in y$.

Now recall that a relation $E$ is extensional when $x=y\iff\{z\mid z\mathrel E x\}=\{z\mid z\mathrel E y\}$.